# Can't connect to remote server using MySQL Workbench on mac

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, workbench

I'm trying to connect to a remote database but it gives me an error that the password is wrong:

> Connecting to MySQL server www.test.net... Access denied for user
>   'test'@'test' (using password: YES)

I know that the password is correct, as I can access to the cpanel with it, but it always gives me the same error, I even tried to change the user to one of the users on that database, but nothing seems to work

**Answer**

It seem this question gets a lot of viewers, so I might as well tell you what solved the problem for me:

I had to give permission to my IP from the server, so that my PC would be recognized as safe to access the DB

Comment: cpanel password may not equal to MySQL login password.

Comment: where can I see that?

Comment: Password cannot be seen, of course. Also, does the MySQL account have remote access? Contact your hosting if necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does the database allow access to the user test from the IP you are making the call to?

In the users table you specify a host from which this user can access the database. Often this may default to localhost or 127.0.0.1

Comment: on the remote server, its says **Server: localhost**, can it be the reason?

Comment: Thanks, I had to give permission to access to my IP, your answer guided me there

Comment: Correct, that's saying that user "test" can only access this from the local machine. So when you try and connect from a remote machine, compooter say no :)

Answer (score 1):

Allow access from all machines :

```
mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'USERNAME'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'PASSWORD' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

Allow access from Machine which ip = x.y.z.t

```
mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'USERNAME'@'x.y.z.t' IDENTIFIED BY 'PASSWORD' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

## Example :

```
 GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'admin'@'172.16.10.34' IDENTIFIED BY 'myp@$$word' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

Answer (score 0):

To allow the user to make the call, you need to do

`GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO test@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx`