# Windows mysql workbench can't connect to remote mysql service

Tags: mysql, windows

I deploy a mysql service on my company remote develop CentOS machine, I'm sure the service is turn on, and it can be access from an other reomte linux machine.

However, I can't connect it from my own Windows PC. I tried mysql workbench client and HeidiSQL client, both failed. I can ping through the remote IP address. I have tried anything  I can found on google. Like

- add `bind-address = 127.0.0.1` to cnf file, and comment out the `skip-networking`.
- I also tried the answer on another question [Can't connect to remote server using MySQL Workbench on mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18400987/cant-connect-to-remote-server-using-mysql-workbench-on-mac), which allow all machine can access to the service.

But my PC still can't connect to it, which report code 10060 error. So what should I do?

Comment: Your windows machine is in the same LAN of the server? I've found [this](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?34,49742,239961#msg-239961), look if it can be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

That `bind-address = 127.0.0.1` config option means that your mysql server only accepts connections from the `localhost`, which is your actual CentOS machine. Make sure to set `bind-address = 0.0.0.0`.

Also, make sure that:

- you have connectivity from your windows machine to the CentOS one
- no firewall blocks the external connections to the local mysql port

Regarding potential security concerns from opening your mysql instance to the whole internet - first make it work, then make it better

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue here man,and i discovered that we need to create a user that isnt the root user. I my case, i don't know why yet, the issue was that.

The solution

Steps:

**1 -** Check the firewall (create a rule for port 3306 or disable it).

**2 -** Comment the line # bind-address=0.0.0.0 at [mysqld] config optin in C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\my.ini

**3 -** Create the user to remote access:

```
 mysql> CREATE USER 'net'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '123';
 mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'net'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

In my case, solved.

Comment: Sounds like, for security, root user was set up to not permit remote access. Thus the need to create another user.